# Error when interacting with an Ethereum Smart Contract using web3.py

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, parity, python, web3.py

I'm using web3.py to interact with an Ethereum Smart Contract which is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Coin {
    address public minter;
    string public name;
    mapping (address => uint) public balances;

    event Sent(address from, address to, uint amount);

    function Coin() public {
        minter = msg.sender;
        name = 'MyCoin';
    }

    // Create new Tokens
    function mint(address _reciever, uint _amount) public {
        if (msg.sender != minter) return;
        balances[_reciever] += _amount;
    }

    // Send tokens
    function send(address _reciever, uint _amount) public {
        if (balances[msg.sender] < _amount) return;
        balances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
        balances[_reciever] += _amount;
        Sent(msg.sender, _reciever, _amount);
    }

    function getBalance(address _user) public view returns (uint){
        return balances[_user];
    }

    function balances(address _account) public view returns (uint, string) {
        return (balances[_account], name);
    }
}
```

Compiling, deploying and generating ABI and contract address were successful. Hower, when i try to access to the deployed smart contract using web3.py i got a strange exception when i call the function `balances()` in the smart contract.

```
eth_abi.exceptions.InsufficientDataBytes: Tried to read 32 bytes.  Only got 0 bytes
```

I used `geth` with a custom genesis block and `parity` chain dev node, but without any success.

Here is my Python code:

```
import json
from web3 import Web3, RPCProvider
from web3.contract import ConciseContract
import time

RPC_IP = '127.0.0.1'
RPC_PORT = '8545'

# read the contract informations then convert them into a Python dict
with open('contract_informations.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

ABI = data.get('abi')
CONTARCT_ADDRESS = data.get('contract_address')

w3 = Web3(RPCProvider(RPC_IP, RPC_PORT))

contract_instance = w3.eth.contract(ABI, CONTARCT_ADDRESS, ContractFactoryClass=ConciseContract)

contract_instance.mint('0x00a329c0648769A73afAc7F9381E08FB43dBEA72', 1000, transact={'from': w3.eth.accounts[0]})


print(contract_instance.getBalance('0x00a329c0648769A73afAc7F9381E08FB43dBEA72'))
```

When i run the Python code there is two exceptions:

```
web3.exceptions.BadFunctionCallOutput: Could not transact with/call contract function, is contract deployed correctly and chain synced?
```

and

```
eth_abi.exceptions.InsufficientDataBytes: Tried to read 32 bytes.  Only got 0 bytes
```

However, when i deploy the contract using `Parity` web interface, everything works fine.

Did, `web3.py` has some limitations or did i miss something ?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Compiling, deploying and generating ABI and contract address were successful.

How do you know deployment was successful? Can you add the code where you wait for the transaction to complete and then you retrieve the contract address?

For what it's worth, a typical compiler would turn your public mapping into a function in the ABI that is exactly equivalent to the `getBalance` that you wrote. So you could also call `contract_instance.balances('0x00a329c0648769A73afAc7F9381E08FB43dBEA72')`.

> However, when i deploy the contract using Parity web interface, everything works fine.

This strongly indicates that something is going wrong during your deployment that you haven't identified. Right now, there is not enough information in the question to debug the deployment.

Comment: The public mapping is named `balances` and there is also a function explicitly declared with the same name `balances` which also takes an address as the only argument. However, the explicitly declared function has a different return type, i.e. `(uint, string)`. Perhaps, this could cause a problem.

Comment: Well the part when i return `(uint, string)` is the part that causes the problem. For example if i modify it to `(uint)` and i modify the functio to return an uint everything goes okay. Otherwise, the same code using parity works fine.

Comment: Also did the mapping balances and the function balances can throw thses errors? Should the variable names and functions have a unique names?

Comment: Thanks to @AjoyBhatia for pointing that out. I'm frankly a bit surprised it compiles this way. Notice that if you switch the visibility on `balances` (the variable) to `private`, that it will *not* compile. Definitely pick a different name for public variables and public functions. Try that and report back.

Comment: @carver did your ran the python code in the question ? did you get a valid response ?

Comment: I am not sure whether variables and functions should have different names, in general. However, in the case of the variable being a mapping, the special thing is that it implicitly defines a function of the same name that takes the key as argument. So here we have two functions - one declared explicitly and another created implicitly because of the mapping, both with the same name and same arguments, i.e. one `address` value.